# Can I use external drive to avoid Jupyter notebook out of memory?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, out-of-memory

I'm training a model and during the training, my Jupyter notebook runs out of memory. I have an external drive of 2Tb. Is it possible to use that memory to run my script and avoid the system crash?

I'd appreciate any suggestions,
Thank you!